# Click on a value in an array of objects returns the value of another key AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, object

I have an array of objects iterated over in a list. If I click on the name, it should alert me with the value of the city the name corresponds to.

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>
    <div ng-controller="AppController">
      <div ng-click="getCity()" ng-repeat="step in steps">
        <p> {{step.name}}</p> 
    </div>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('AppController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.steps = [
        {name: "ABC", status: true, city: "Boston"},
        {name: "DEF", status: true, city: "New York"},
        {name: "GHI", status: true, city: "LA"}
];

        $scope.getCity = function(a) {

    }
});
```

[Detailed code here.](http://jsfiddle.net/rX7ba/309/)

--> So I click on "ABC" and "Boston" should be shown to me.

Appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: So what should be the function to return the value of city?

Comment: I've answered, but in future you should really tell us what you've tried and what didn't work. If you've tried nothing then you can easily find the answer in the AngularJS docs.

Comment: Sorry about that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a value to your `getCity` function:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  $scope.steps = [{
      name: "ABC",
      status: true,
      city: "Boston"
    },
    {
      name: "DEF",
      status: true,
      city: "New York"
    },
    {
      name: "GHI",
      status: true,
      city: "LA"
    }
  ];

  $scope.getCity = function(step) {
    alert(step.city)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp'>
  <div ng-controller="AppController">
    <div ng-click="getCity(step)" ng-repeat="step in steps">
      <p> {{step.name}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```